# UICollectionView - Update Array indexPath based on Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Hi I m using two collection cell to display data, Child Collection view values are based on main Collection View.

I have Video List and when i select Video In Table i m passing Complete array at index path, so that the main collection view will be displayed based on selected indexPath of array.

it is displaying fine, but when i scroll it horizontal, I an passing visible cell indexPath data to fetch child collection View Data.

But when i scroll Main Collection View , The array at indexPath is not updating based on Main Collection View it always display same IndexPath which is Passed From Video List(Previous View Controller).

How to update main collection view array based on horizontal Scrolling.

I want ion this scenario-

**For example VIdeo list array is 1,2,3,4**

i select 3 index and pass to collection view for videolist array, it displayed selected index path row value, when i scroll right side the index path should get increased to 4 on right and left it should decrease to 2, for any values selected on video list array. Main Collection view should work based on passed index path and act based on its index path

My Code-

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 if(self.childCollectionView ==collectionView)
 {
    return [self.array_ChildElements count];
}
else
{
    return [self.array_VideoList count];
}
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (collectionView ==self.collectionView)
{
    VVCollectionCell *cell = (VVCollectionCell *)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"VVCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    VVSystems *obj;
    if (self.iscalledFromVideoLIst)
    {
        obj =self.array_VideoList[self.selectedIndexPath.row];

    }
    else
    {
        obj =self.array_VideoList[indexPath.row];
    }
    [self.collectionView flashScrollIndicators];

    NSLog(@"Current Index Path--->%ld",(long)self.selectedIndexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"Current Title--->%@",obj.title);

    [cell.labelVideoTitle setText:obj.title];
    [cell.imgVideo sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj.iconImage]
                     placeholderImage:nil];

    return cell;
}
else
{
    childCollectionCell *cell2 = (childCollectionCell *)[self.childCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"childCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ChildAnimations *obj = self.array_ChildElements[indexPath.row];
    [self.childCollectionView flashScrollIndicators];

    [cell2.labelTitel setText:obj.tagName];
    [cell2.imgbackGround sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj.image]
                     placeholderImage:nil];
    return cell2;
}
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

for (VVCollectionCell *cell in [self.collectionView visibleCells])
{
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];


    VVSystems *objCustVehiclesList =self.array_VideoList[newIndexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Current Index Path Row -->%ld",(long)newIndexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"Current Title--->%@",objCustVehiclesList.title);


    self.str_partID =objCustVehiclesList.partID;
    [self ServiceCallForChildVideo:self.str_partID];
    self.iscalledFromVideoLIst = NO;

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: its very tough , to hold the current position , the reason is the subclass of scrollview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik then what s the solution for this

Comment: can you show the screen shot which type u try

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik plz check this. i m passogn correct array index and it displaying correct but when i scroll it takes 2 elemts from array. and display wrong objectin collection view. if i select 3 object in array and passed to collection view and scroll to right it should show 4 and 2 for left. but it showing 2 from array

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik have u checked screen shot i have updated in question

Answer (score 0):

i see ,if you want to scroll both left and right with videoList datas.

the right way is that when the VC call "viewDidLoad",  the last line add :

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
```

and edit the code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (collectionView ==self.collectionView)
{
    VVCollectionCell *cell = (VVCollectionCell *)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"VVCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   // VVSystems *obj;
   // if (self.iscalledFromVideoLIst)
   // {
   //     obj =self.array_VideoList[self.selectedIndexPath.row];

   // }
   // else
   //  {
   //     obj =self.array_VideoList[indexPath.row];
   // }
    VVSystems *obj=self.array_VideoList[indexPath.row];
    [self.collectionView flashScrollIndicators];

    NSLog(@"Current Index Path--->%ld",(long)self.selectedIndexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"Current Title--->%@",obj.title);

    [cell.labelVideoTitle setText:obj.title];
    [cell.imgVideo sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj.iconImage]
                     placeholderImage:nil];

    return cell;
}
else
{
    childCollectionCell *cell2 = (childCollectionCell *)[self.childCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"childCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ChildAnimations *obj = self.array_ChildElements[indexPath.row];
    [self.childCollectionView flashScrollIndicators];

    [cell2.labelTitel setText:obj.tagName];
    [cell2.imgbackGround sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj.image]
                     placeholderImage:nil];
    return cell2;
}
}
```

Comment: if i do as u suggested , it override selected index path to 0 index path, so first elements s only displayed for any valued selected at previous videoList View COntroller

Comment: i don't know if i see,but i have two ideas: 1、when u select Video In Table,you can scroll Main Collection View to the selectedIndexPath ；2、 use the new datas for Main Collection View(when u select Video In Table , change Main Collection View's data And refresh it)

Comment: when i scroll for example .. i have 1,2,3,4,5 in video list array. Now i selected 3 index from array and passed to collection view and it displayed 3 object in array in collection view. now when, i scroll right side, the videolist array index should be increased from 3 to fourth and if i scroll left side it should decrease from 3 to 2

Comment: please check my updated question. my problem is on scrolling main collection view array.

Comment: could you show the code  when u select Video In Table?

Comment: (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VVSystems *objVehicleVisualVideosList = [self.array_VideoLists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    VideoGalleryVC *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VideoGalleryVC"];
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [controller setSelectedIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
    [controller setArray_VideoList:self.array_VideoLists];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

Comment: how it could be correct, i m passing index path 3 from videl list pasge but in cell for row at iondex path u r settign it 0. so it alswys start from 0 elemnst in array in collection view

Comment: really disappointing same thing u r telling again and again. now i m getting only first elemnts in collection view if i come from 3 index in array. now it print from 0 index in collection view

Answer (score 0):

They way you are finding the visible cell is correct.
I doubt in your conditions here

```
if (self.iscalledFromVideoLIst)
    {
        obj =self.array_VideoList[self.selectedIndexPath.row];

    }
    else
    {
        obj =self.array_VideoList[indexPath.row];
    }
```

Which might be giving you different index path.  I don't know when you are setting this value self.iscalledFromVideoLIst

A different approach is to use.
cell.labelVideoTitle.tag=indexPath.row;
but don't put this inside the condition.
And access the label title in your

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

method.

Mainly you need to debug your method and see what is the indexPath coming the time you are scrolling, the issue is mainly here. Try to print the indexPath.row here and you will see the issue.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: when i scroll , it always takes 2 elements from array and display in collection view cell. but that is not the case, when i scroll the main collection view array index should get updated on scrolling , whether it right or left, so in all scenarios when i scroll it takes 2 index of array. but i want the current index,

Comment: First try to debug your cellForItemAtIndexPath method and see what IndexPath is coming there when you are scrolling, this will guide you in right direction. Without this info I won't be able to help you further.

Comment: i debugged, when i scoll it takes only 2 value of array if i m coming from 4 elements

Comment: i debuged,  what s the passed index value, same im getting while scrolling and that same value is being passed to cell for row at indexpath. but it should be next value of array

Comment: So you are getting same value for your indexPath.row. And also check whats the value in your array self.array_VideoList, Hope you are not resetting it and reloading the collection view. It should be containing all the values for your items. Because you are only getting 2 records in your array, I doubt so and your numberOfItemsInSection method is returning 2 rows then. Please check your array then.

Comment: same array i m disp[laying video list view i m passing in collection view and indexpath for selected item. problem is in scrolling elemnts when i scroll it should scroll adjacnet elemnts left or right based on scrol, but u r not getting this. ur always askign problem in array and debug.

Comment: Very rude way of commenting. It looks like that you don't want to put your efforts and want to have a ready piece of cake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118795/discussion-between-imran-and-sabby).

Comment: @ Sabby u r askign samee question again and again
i have tried my all debug tehn only askign in stack
but u r telling which i have tried before. U could not find solution just leave it. y r u frustarating if u could not answer it. please answer if u know, i have given sufficient info. What u have answered, u can give it in comments, its not an answer.