# Correct way to Synthesize objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, declaration

I have been synthesizing objects in my .m file this way:

```
@synthesize myObject;
```

And if I have many objects, I do it like this:

```
@synthesize myObject1, myObject2, myObject3;
```

However I see some people synthesize this way:

```
@synthesize myObject = _myObject;
```

Can somebody explain which is better way to synthesize the object?

Comment: Which is consuming your time that is best.

Comment: 2 is fine, 3 is just specifying the backing ivars name explicitly, so only if you need to rename the ivar do you need to use 3

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658142/purpose-of-synthesize

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik could u check it http://stackoverflow.com/q/38692637/2522603

Comment: You could just stop using `@synthesize`, except for the usually rare cases where it's needed.

Comment: Fenix, thanks. Avi, don't think we can stop synthesise since any controls not synthesised will not be detected by compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :
Ans 1 :

```
- (void)setCoolWord:(NSString *) myObject {
          _myObject = myObject;
    }

- (NSString *) myObject {
    return _myObject;
}
```

Hope it helped.

```
with Xcode 4.5 or up. The IDE write the @synthesize statement for you.

The @synthesize statement is only write the setter and getter for you.

that, _variable_name is the instant variable.

The variable_name is only a method that returns the value of _variable_name by default.

when using the variable = <Statement or value>. its calling thesetVarable_Namemethod to set the_variable_name` by default.
```

Comment: u r doing it by getter and setter method, which Xcode automatically does bcoz of ARC

Comment: Xcode doesn't do anything, it's the compiler and the devices doing that.

Answer (score 0):

1. in .h like this,

2.@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fullName;

3.do in .m where you want there written like this by using self or (_).

4. self.fullName (or) _fullName  ;